# For the finite BYTE of Octal numbers

Tags: assembly, modular-arithmetic

For the finite BYTE of Octal numbers R<sub>8</sub> = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,1,..,N}

The number in BYTE R<sub>8</sub>: N<sub>8</sub> = (7<sub>8</sub>)<sup>5</sup> MOD (400<sub>8</sub>) = ___?______

Can someone please help me answer this. I got 247<sub>8</sub>, but I am unsure if this is correct.

Thank you

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: I didn't use any code, I just did the math by hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the result is correct. `7^5=16807`, `400` octal is `256` decimal, `16807 mod 256 = 167` and `167` in octal is `247`.

You should have showed your steps like this in the question.